# How do I map entities in GORM when pk of one references pk of another

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

What is the best way to map two entities in GORM when the primary key of one table is also a foreign key from another table. For ex:

Here is one table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_a` (
`a_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
PRIMARY KEY (`a_id`)
)
```

And the pk of this table 'a_id' is referenced by the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_b` (
`b_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`b_id`), 
 KEY `b_id_fk` (`b_id`), 
 CONSTRAINT `b_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`b_id`) REFERENCES `table_a' (`a_id`)
 )
```

How do I map the above two entities in Grails/GORM? The following code will obviously not work since GORM will throw exception saying 'repeated column in mapping for entity'.

```
class TableB {

 TableA tableA
 static belongsTo = [TableA]

 static mapping = {
    id column:"b_id"
    version false
    tableA column:"b_id"
 }

 static constraints = {
    tableA unique: true
 }
}
```

Note: I'm using grails 1.3.7 but can switch to a newer version if this problem is an issue that has recently been fixed. Please let me know.

Comment: can you change the schema or do you have to have the primary key also be the fk?

Comment: I know the schema is not as per best practices. But it's a legacy database which I cannot change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it applies to your case, but one thing you can do is map `TableB` as a subclass of `TableA` using table-per-subclass inheritance strategy. Check [Inheritance Strategies](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.2.3%20Inheritance%20Strategies) in the Grails guide.

So, you'd have:

```
class TableA {
    static mapping = {
        id column: 'a_id'
        table 'table_a'
        version false
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }
}

class TableB extends TableA {
    static mapping = {
        id column: 'b_id'
        table 'table_b'
        version false
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that you can't create a `TableB` object after you have created the `TableA` object. The way Hibernate works, when you create a new `TableA` instance, a record in `table_a` is created. When you create a new `TableB` instance, both a record in `table_a` and a record in `table_b` are created, with the same id.

OTOH, I can't think of a valid reason for that schema other than the mapping of a class hierarchy like this.

Comment: Yes you're right, this is using table-per-subclass inheritance strategy. I've tested that setting the tablePerHierarchy flag to false makes it work as expected. Thanks for your help!